# System crashes when using two particular RAM together

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, memory, crash

Here are the RAM stick I have:

A) 16 GB (Model 1 Crucial Ballistix BLS16G4S26BFSD)

B) 32 GB (Model 2 HyperX HX426S16IB/32)

C) 32 GB (Model 2 HyperX HX426S16IB/32)

Note: B and C have everything the same including brand, model, capacity, and frequency.

My issue is when I use: A & B  = No problems, A & C  = No problems, but B & C  = Constant crash and unable to boot

I have run a memory test on B & C individually but no issues. Also when I installed B & C for the first time, it worked fine without any issue for like 30 minutes. But now every time I install B & C, system crash in Windows boot screen (it will boot and then go back to BitLocker password screen and repeat).

Note: I was able to get a blue screen but only during first two times. No BSOD screen since. The error message first two times were `Whea uncorrectable error` and `hypervisor error`.

**Update:** I tried a few more things.

Booting in Ubuntu, Windows installation USB also fails.

My laptop is Clevo N957TP6 and I have UEFI enabled.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: We need to know the exact models of your computer, motherboard and RAM sticks.

Comment: @harrymc I've updated it.

Comment: About the details of the A) Crucial RAM could you provide a model number please?

Comment: @TamalesRancheros Found it. BLS16G4S26BFSD

Answer (score 1):

You can only use up to 32GB of RAM on that specific model of Laptop

> Two 260 Pin SO-DIMM Sockets Supporting DDR4 2400MHz Memory
>
> Memory Expandable from 8GB (minimum) up to 32GB(maximum)
>
> Compatible with 4GB, 8GB or 16GB Modules

From [N950TP6 / N957TP6 - CLEVO Computer](https://clevo-computer.com/media/pdf/78/04/79/N950TP6_SM_20171212.pdf) Service Manual

Comment: I am currently using 48 GB (16+32) without any issue.

Comment: maybe it needs a bios update for it to use the whole 64gb of ram
so far i had no luck finding a download link for something like that. 
only this [link](https://www.clevo.com.tw/clevo_down.asp?lang=en)

Comment: Yeah. But it works fine sometime. There is no update for BIOS available anyway.

Comment: I saw that you already posted on other forum, on that particular one i found an unofficial repo for bios updates but i lost the link for you to check it out (it was around page 34, i read the whole thread) .
For me there is no issue to address here since the manufacturer Clevo specifies that the maximum amount of RAM for your laptop is 32Gb. 
I noticed that other companies like XMG or Obsidian offer updates (since they use the same manufacturer) maybe you could try those but obviously at your own risk too

Comment: Found it! [repo link](https://repo.palkeo.com/clevo-mirror/N9xTP6/)

Comment: @VarunAgw: You are using non-standard RAM configurations, not foreseen by the manufacturer. Some may work more or less and others may not, at your risk.

Comment: @harrymc B and C are the same brands, same everything. How is it non-standard?

Comment: @TamalesRancheros I am not hardware-expert so not really interested in risking-bricking my laptop. But thank you for the research.

Comment: @VarunAgw: The motherboard was conceived for RAM sticks of 8 GB & 16 GB, so a total maximum of 32 GB. The 32 GB sticks (if they even work in full) were not foreseen, so you're in an uncharted area. This means that for whatever works you should be thankful, and whatever doesn't work cannot be forced.

Comment: @harrymc Ok. So I just want to confirm again that you feel this is a motherboard support issue? Buying RAM from a different brand won't solve it?

Comment: @harrymc I am curious because I am able to power on and even run the system earlier. BIOS also correct detect 64 GB RAM everytime.

Comment: @VarunAgw: You are exceeding the manufacturer specs, so whatever works, works. A different brand might not help. I can't advice here, except for getting another computer that is certified for that much memory.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, understood. Thanks